# Why it's occuring invalidArgumenterror:Graph execution error while training my model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

InvalidArgumentError

Cell In[57], line 2 1 EPOCHS=25

> 2 history-model.fit( 3 train_ds,

4 epochs EPOCHS,

5 batch_size-batch_size,

6 verbose=1,

7 validation_data=val_ds

8)

File -/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback utils.py:70, in filter traceack lacala

.error handler(*args, **kwargs) filtered_tb = _process traceback frames (e.*traceback*)

> 67

68 #To get the full stack trace, call:

69

#tf.debugging.disable traceback_filtering()" raise e.with traceback(filtered tb) from None

70

71 finally:

72 del filtered tb

In []:(https://stackoverflow.com)

This is the error occuring while I'm training my tensorflow model..please suggest me any solutions to resolve it.